# Import grid text file to shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, grids-graticules

I'm working with the Climate Change forecasts from the Hadley Center Climate Model (HADCM3) available here: http://www.ipcc-data.org/sres/hadcm3_download.html

They have many different forecasts and I'm working with the file: HADCM3_A1F_TEMP_1980.tar.gz. It seems to be a grid text file, and includes information for several different months, so it has headers at the start and also in the middle of the text:

[image: Snapshot of first header]

[image: Snapshot of header in the middle of the text]

What is the best way to import these seemingly txt files (maybe they are some other format I'm not familiar with) to QGIS, and save them as shapefiles? I've managed to extract them using 7zip, but I don't know how to proceed from there. I'm working on Windows and QGIS 2.16.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://www.ipcc-data.org/sres/hadcm3_grid.html : The grid is 96*73 large, with cellsizes of 3.75x2.5 degrees. Note that Eastings are from 0 to 360.

There is no easy way to load the data into QGIS, you need to combine Latitude, Longitude and value from different tables. Usually this is done using Python (or else) code.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any source of model code or template I could use that you can think of? I'm not an expert on how to handle grids honestly.

Comment: Unfortuantely, I can't help out with code.